# Can we add application(link) from Windows Store to our system(software center -sccm)?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, sccm

I want to add application from Windows store to our system(sccm) via link( Dont know is there any other way). Is it possible if yes how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With SCCM 2012 SP1, this indeed is possible.

In your SCCM console, Application Management / Applications, create a new app, based on the Windows Store.

You do need one reference machine where you installed the apps from the store manually, then you 'import' that into SCCM and reference it.

That should get you going :)